# Vertically align text within Objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC (latest version) and although I have been working with Illustrator for many years, I only do small vector related things in it, so by no means an expert.

I would like to align a bit of text inside a rectangle object, so I select both, then I tell it to align relative to rectangle, and press the Vertically Align Center option, but this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, it is NOT vertically centered, what am I doing wrong?

This seems to behave this way with text only! I'm sure if I changed the text to paths and did the alignment, I'd get the result I'm after, but must I do this? Is there no easier way?

**UPDATE:**

Following solution provided by duplication link still doesn't work for me! Am I missing something? I applied the `Effect` > `Path` > `Outline Object`

Here is what I get:

[image: image 2]

Thank You.

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the above... The answer is that illustrator is vertically aligning the bounding box, the solution is what you've linked to or to expand the outlines, but loose editability of the text... I wish Adobe would fix this issue.

Comment: It's not an Illustrator issue. It's an issue with the font file from the font foundry. There's nothing for Adobe to fix.

Comment: see update, I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: It would appear you didn't follow *all* the steps in the duplicate link.

Comment: When it says `Preferences` does it mean Illustrator's main preferences? cause I can't see Preview Bounds anywhere :(

Comment: @Ciwan Edit -> Preferences -> General. it is one of the checkboxes. Or hit ctrl + k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not missing anything.. And even Adobe Illustrator is doing it's job very well.. Look at the below image
[image]

1. **Text** is shown as selected and as you can see it is perfectly aligned in the centre! The problem is all type faces have different line-heights so what Illustrator does is.. it aligns based on text's line height
2. **Path (Outlined)** as you can see after converting text to outlines it aligns visible!
3. **Rasterized** and text also carries it's line height property and takes up the space accordingly.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

"This seems to behave this way with text only! I'm sure if I changed the text to paths and did the alignment, I'd get the result I'm after, but must I do this? Is there no easier way?"

No, there is no easier way.